# how to change the templates for the generic django cms plugins?

Tags: django-cms

I want to change the output template or extend the template of the Text and Video plugins that are some of the generic Django CMS plugins.
how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plugins use the Django template engine, this allows you to override any template at the project level.

So if the text plugin looks for a template in `cms/plugins/text.html`, you can override this template by adding `cms/plugins/text.html` in a folder that is on your `TEMPLATES` directory.

Comment: To make the above good advise concrete: create that `cms/plugins/text.html` under the `templates` folder of your django site.  But check the configuration of your `settings.TEMPLATES` to understand the search order you're actually using.